# How to determine cursor current position using native JS

Tags: javascript

How to determine current mouse cursor coordinates using only native `JS`? I know that we can use [jQuery mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), but I think that it's bad idea to include the `jQuery` for handling a `mousemove` event only.

Comment: Coordinates relative to what? The page, a container?

Comment: jQuery mousemove is just an interface to the standard Javascript mousemove event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same way as in jQuery

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'position : ' + e.pageX + ' x ' + e.pageY;
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6cBKp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    alert('position : ' + e.pageX + ' x ' + e.pageY)
}, false);
```

Comment: You might also want to check if e is set. As I recall older IE Browsers have a global event object, so first line in the function could be something like `e = e || event`

Comment: @beipawel - older IE doesn't support addEventListener, so not really an issue. Good copy of the answer BTW.